# Can I include other template into template?

Tags: theming

I override template in my custom theme na (`templates/block--[module]--[delta].tpl.php`) and I would like to include other template (from the same directory) into this. Can I do it and how?

Directory structure

```
sites\all\themes\
   my_name_of_theme\
        templates\
             block--views--front-page-block-1.tpl.php
             example-file-template.tpl.php
```

`block--views--front-page-block-1.tpl.php` (concept what I want to do):

```
<?php 
     /* init $path (or maybe it is not needed) */
     include($path . 'example-file-template.tpl.php');
?>
```

Comment: [`include`](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.include.php) it, maybe? What have you tried? What is your problem, exactly?

Comment: Please, take a look on my edit @Mołot

Comment: "or maybe it is not needed" - have you tried, with and without? If so, why "maybe"? If not - why not? it would take you a few minutes to try. Far less than asking a question here.

Comment: It was only contept - I don't even know how to it. Normal include doesn't work.  There is variable `$path` to highlight that maybe I need to create/generate path but I don't know how

Comment: What have you tried and how it failed should be directly in your question. You say there was code you were using and it failed - so post what have you tried into your question, with description of *how* it failed.

Comment: @kspacja `drupal_get_path('theme', 'my_name_of_theme ')` gets you what you need

Comment: Please include Drupal version as well either in title or as tag, that will help in better answering.

Comment: @AshishBairagi Actually, we actively discourage precisely that practice. If you actually read the tag description, you will see that. :)

Comment: Is the template you want to include another proper drupal template (defined with hook_theme()) or just a random file of html/php?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get another drupal theme path with `drupal_get_path('theme', 'theme_name');` and finally

```
<?php 
     include(drupal_get_path('theme', 'theme_name').'/example-file-template.tpl.php');
?>
```

Comment: also path_to_theme() works for the current theme, and is shorter.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong yes, but he need to use the theme files in current theme .so need use path of not default theme .

Answer (score 0):

You can use path to theme (Uses the current allowed theme):

```
<?php
include(path_to_theme().'/templates/TEMPLATE_NAME.tpl.php');
?>
```

Or Drupal get the path (You can set the theme you want to use):

```
<?php
    include(drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME_NAME').'/templates/TEMPLATE_NAME.tpl.php');
?>
```